# WSO2 Governance Registry C-App (CAR File) deployment

Tags: wso2

I am trying to step through the points demonstrated in the webinar (http://wso2.com/library/webinars/2012/08/enterprise-use-case-webinar-application-governance-wso2-governance-registry), wherein I can use the Governance Registry to -

1) Deploy C-App file to servers in Development Environment - (This is where I am running into a problem) 
2) Manage the Lifecycle of this app by promoting it from Dev->QA -> PreProd-> Prod

My use case has the following set of servers in each environment (Dev, QA, PreProd, Prod)

i) App Server 
ii) ESB Server 
iii) DSS Server

The CAR file has artifacts specific to each of the above servers.

Based on what was demonstrated, I created the 3 asset models - Server, Environment, Project within the Governance Registry.

I defined each of the above servers in the Server Meta Data configuration. 
Next, I created an Environment - (Dev) and associated all the Dev Servers with this Environment. 
Finally, I built a Project - Uploaded my CAR file and associated it with the Dev Environment. At this point when I click on Save Project, I do not see my CAR file deployed to the respective servers in my Dev environment.

Is there any configuration that must be done within the Governance Registry in order to get the CAR file deployed to the Dev Environment servers?

Note that my CAR file deploys fine when I upload it manually on these Dev Servers.

Any idea on how can I get the CAR deployment done via G-Reg.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the setup provided in the webinar is not supported out of the box and you need some customizations for it. Further, this model is now deprecated.

Pls refer this[1] documentation for governing external references across different environments.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance460/Governing+External+References+Across+Environments

Regards,
Gillian